# Web.config - allow authentication mode to be altered for each deployment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

Assuming web software is deployed to multiple customers, there may be a requirement to have a different authentication mode set for each customer.

Let's say 1 customer wants to use forms authentication, and the other wants to use Windows authentication - this can be managed by setting the authentication mode accordingly in the Web.config file.

However, when a software update is deployed to them, how can I get a new Web.config file to them without overwriting their authentication mode?

Would an include file do the job (so that the settings are held outside of Web.config), or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: How do you currently deploy software updates? Is it a basic copy operation?

Comment: Yes. The publish output is copied to the target web server, and this includes the Web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Two options

### Set the authentication mode programmatically

You could customize your code so that the authentication mode is set programmatically, perhaps based on a business rule setting in the client's database instance.

For example, this sets windows authentication mode:

```
String applicationPath = String.Format("{0}/{1}", _server.Sites["Default Web Site"].Name, "AppName");

Configuration config = _server.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();

ConfigurationSection anonymousAuthenticationSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication", applicationPath);

anonymousAuthenticationSection["enabled"] = false;

ConfigurationSection windowsAuthenticationSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication", applicationPath);

windowsAuthenticationSection["enabled"] = true;

_server.CommitChanges();
```

### Use a separate config file

Or, you could "outsource" the configuration to a separate config file that is distributed per client, , e.g. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417062/how-to-use-partial-config-files).

```
<authentication configSource="ConfigFiles\authentication.config" />
```

### Do both

You could code your site so that it picks the config source for the authentication settings programmatically, perhaps based on the host header in the incoming http request.

```
authenticationSection.ConfigSource = String.Format("d:\Configurations\{0}.config", HttpContext.Current.Request.Host);
```

Then you distribute the secondary config file per client.

`FirstCustomer.com.config`

`SomeOtherCustomer.com.config`

`YetAnother.net.config`

See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource(v=vs.110).aspx).